# jquery ignoring first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
   NewShowHideDiv2(iconID, divID, disabled) {
    var x = document.getElementById(divID);
    var y = document.getElementById(iconID);
    $(eval(y)).click(function() {
    console.log(eval(y));
     $(eval(y)).toggleClass( "clicked" );

     });
   $(eval(x)).slideToggle("slow", function() {

    });
}
```

All i am trying to get it to do is toggle the "clicked" class on click. However, it ignores the first and second  click, and then applies it on the third and all subsequent odd number clicks. any ideas?

Comment: Why are you calling `eval()` on an Element?

Comment: besides the issue Taplar mentioned, it seems binding click event again and again caused the error.

Comment: you should read about `eval` : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: what do u want it to do ?

Comment: it's legacy code i'm working with, thus the (eval) . I'm all for getting rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how `NewShowHideDiv2` is called it's difficult to be certain but there are some likely issues.

First, by putting your click binding function inside another function, the event isn't bound to the element until `NewShowHideDiv2` is run. So you'll want to pull that out and put it in something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(eval(y)).click(function() {
        console.log(eval(y));
        $(eval(y)).toggleClass( "clicked" );

    });
});
```

Also, the eval approach on the JS object is likely causing issues and certainly isn't the best practice. You'll want to modify that to be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#iconIDHere").click(function() {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).toggleClass( "clicked" );

    });

    function NewShowHideDiv2(divID, disabled) {
        $("#" + divID).slideToggle("slow", function() {

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with vanilla JS:

```
var x = document.getElementById('divID');
x.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('clicked')) {
        e.target.classList.remove('clicked');
    } else {
        e.target.classList.add('clicked');
    }
});
```

I think JQuery is:

```
$('#divID').click(function() {
    $('#divID').toggleClass('clicked');
});
```